# Как мне добавить Entry в мой код?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Я пытался добавить Entry разными способами, но похоже нужно через canvas. Как мне это сделать? Добавил фрагмент кода с Tkinter

```
#=========================================================== Ход работы

error = 0
root = tk.Tk() # Задаем новое окно

root.geometry('400x500') # Определяем размеры
root.resizable(width=False, height=False) # Закрепляем размеры
root.title("Голосовой ассистент Юля")

#======= Непонятный код ======

image = Image.open("Background.png")
width = 500
ratio = (width / float(image.size[0]))
height = int((float(image.size[1]) * float(ratio)))
image = image.resize((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=width, height=height)
canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand="no")
canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=image)

#==============================

canvas.create_text(200, 25, text="Юлия 0.1.5", fill="Purple", font='Helvetica 30') # Текст
canvas.create_text(200, 50, text="Голосовой помощник, созданный для общения", fill="Purple", font='Times 13') # Текст

button = tk.Button(root, text='Запуск', font="Times 30", bg=_from_rgb((189, 223, 249))) # Настройки для кнопки
canvas.create_window((125, 400), anchor="nw", window=button) # Вывод кнопки.
button.config(command=lambda: main()) # Вызов кнопкой функции main()
Program = tk.Entry(root, width=10) <-- ПРОБЛЕМНОЕ МЕСТО
Program.pack() <-- ПРОБЛЕМНОЕ МЕСТО



root = tk.mainloop() # Запуск окна

#==========================================================
```

Проблема в том, что поле для ввода не появляется. Почему canvas? Потому что код из области "Непонятный код" был взят с другого вопроса и менять что либо в нём я не желаю и не могу.

Comment: 1 - в чем заключается проблема в проблемном месте? Если возникает ошибка, укажите ее в вопросе. 2 - зачем добавлять через canvas?

Comment: Поправил в конце

Answer (score 0):

Текстовое поле у вас появляется ниже canvas, за пределами окна. Если убрать строку с указанием размера окна (`root.geometry('400x500')`), то его будет видно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если нужно добавить поле ввода поверх canvas, то добавляйте его аналогично добавлению кнопки `button` (в скобках `(300, 400)` - координаты, по которым будет расположено поле на `canvas`):

```
button = tk.Button(root, text='Запуск', font="Times 30") # Настройки для кнопки
canvas.create_window((125, 400), anchor="nw", window=button) # Вывод кнопки.
button.config(command=lambda: main()) # Вызов кнопкой функции main()

Program = tk.Entry(root, width=10)
canvas.create_window((300, 400), anchor="nw", window=Program)
```

Результат:

[image: Результат]

Comment: Хм... А у меня Entry сразу видна была. Причём прямо поверх кнопки.

Comment: Спасибо громадное! Теперь я знаю  какд обавлять через канвас!  Просто вписывать window="Нужная переменная с функцией"! Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @DarkHacker, если ответ помог, вы можете отметить его принятым, для этого поставьте галку слева от него.